# Can anyone explain how high atmospheric pressure affects fishing when water cant be compressed?

Tags: pressure

So, I am both a qualified scuba diver, and a fisherman.

I understand that for every (approximate!) 10m you go down under water, you add an atmosphere of pressure, and things get squeezed. Conversely, when you come up from the depths, things  expand (such as the air in your lungs if you hold your breath while you do it! - Not a good idea by the way).

"They" say that when atmospheric pressure goes over 1022mb the fish seem to go off the feed and fishing in general becomes harder. I get that water can get squeezed sideways to lower pressure areas and this is one of the reasons we get different tide heights.

I'd like to understand why this is given that water is very hard to compress and at your average fishing depths from a boat (100ft or so) these subtle changes in atmospheric pressure would make little to no difference to the fish.

Suppose a fish spends the majority of its time at 10m say, regardless of it that's at the bottom or not, then the pressure at 10m deep would remain very close to constant. Even if it did rise, surely the fish would only need to swim a few cm higher to negate the rise in pressure at that depth, and therefore the fish would be in exactly the same situation as if it were in lower pressure? Is the same true if there is low air pressure? The water (due to the tide) would actually be higher, hence more water over the area and therefore greater water pressure (especially on bottom dwelling fish).

I just don't understand it when people say higher air pressure can affect fishing so much, and would like to understand.

I'm by no means a scientist so if someone could explain this in fairly simple terms I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: [Possible source example](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3625024.pdf?casa_token=TP9AWfqmJlUAAAAA:pZhZ-ha5Oywd6S6UwXj0Ojh_Sq9ZF0OXi6OIx6pSdPyX3nFqreC5P5GoKUYq-KkWzA8P11nU68G4_XtMGFHZZJC5ypHesGfY8iSZa-kSskQ4h0JRDg), since none was provided. This seems to be a zoological/oceanographic/meteorological question rather than a physics question; barometric pressure changes are intrinsically linked to weather changes, sediment movement, anatomical changes, etc. This is much more complex than a [hydrostatic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium) model.

Comment: One can discuss the solubility of a gas at different atmospheric pressures and temperatures, this would certainly affect marine life relying on dissolved oxygen. I don't personally know that the effect is large or what the specific numbers are though off hand.

Comment: The effect is essentially proportional. Chemists call the rule governing the solubility of gas-phase particles in solution Henry's law, and each solute-solvent pair has its own Henry's law constant. One consequence of this is that as you double the pressure, you essentially double the amount of dissolved gases in a solution. When applied to nitrogen and your blood, this is the cause of divers getting the "bends" from resurfacing too quickly; the gas will very rapidly form bubbles in your veins which are extremely painful. I can only surmise that something similar can happen to fish.

Comment: If the tale is true, that doesn't necessarily mean that the fish respond to changes in pressure. Maybe they're responding to something else. Atmospheric pressure doesn't just change for no reason. The changes are a symptom of wind and weather. Maybe there's some _other_ symptom of wind and weather—something that correlates with atmospheric pressure—to which the fish respond.